# Prolog - How to pass data from database (asserted) into a list?

Tags: prolog

Basically, I have asserted several structures using `assert`.

This database can be listed by querying `listing(myData).`, and it'd print something like (in the console):

```
animal(cat) 
animal(bird) 
animal(human) 
animal(elephant)
```

I want to know if there's a way I can create a rule that "returns" a list that contains all these elements.

So I should be able to have a list with the form `[animal(cat), animal(bird), animal(human), animal(elephant), ...]`

Thanks in advance. (Please don't ask why I want to do this)

Comment: `F = animal(_), findall(F, F, Fs)`

Answer (score 0):

Here a little example that demonstrates usage of `bagof` and `findall` with various generators:

```
:-initialization(main).

animal(cat).
animal(bird).
animal(human).
animal(elephant).

main :- 
  write("bagof animal(_)      : "),bagof(animal(X), animal(X), Bag), write(Bag), nl,
  write("bagof generator(42,_): "),bagof(generator(42, Y), animal(Y), Bag2), write(Bag2), nl,
  write("bagof _              : "),bagof(Y, animal(Y), Bag4), write(Bag4), nl,
  write("findall gen(35,_)    : "),findall(gen(35, Z), animal(Z), Bag3), write(Bag3), nl,
  halt.
```

The output:

```
bagof animal(_)      : [animal(cat),animal(bird),animal(human),animal(elephant)]
bagof generator(42,_): [generator(42,cat),generator(42,bird),generator(42,human),generator(42,elephant)]
bagof _              : [cat,bird,human,elephant]
findall gen(35,_)    : [gen(35,cat),gen(35,bird),gen(35,human),gen(35,elephant)]
```